# Programmatically retrieve selection of context menu

Tags: c#, c++, file, contextmenu

this question is basically me asking how to go about writing something that will do the above mentioned. I'll explain it in the physical first:

I'm not sure if everyone is familiar with DropBox but for those of you who don't this is what you need to know. To share a file/picture publicly you basically right click on the physical file, from the context menu select DropBox->Copy Public Link.

Now to do this for, lets say, 100 files is very tedious, hence I wish to write something to do this for me. Now my question is, is it even possible. And if yes, which language do I need to do it in, i.e. does C# even have the capability to do something like this or would I need to go C++.

i.e. I would like the program to do this: RClick->DropBox->Copy Public Link, GoTo next file, RClick->DropBox->Copy Public Link, GoTo next file, etc, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The menu items appear via Dropbox shell extension registered with the file object. You can instantiate the same extension programmatically repeating behavior of Windows shell, and call [IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776097%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make shell extension initialize the commands, and then call [IContextMenu::InvokeCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make it copy what you need into clipboard. That is, it is possible to automate shell command.

Otherwise, you might want to check Dropbox API to see if they are providing the same service in a regular API way.